# After add attribute clearance_price as price, it doesn't be calculated for finalprice on Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2, attributes, price, tierprice, product-detail-page

I use **special_price**, **tier_price** and **clearance_price** and need to display minimal price of them as **final price**.
I added **clearance_price** and **custom attribute** and put it in **Advanced pricing**.
But when I do to **product details page** it doesn't show clearance price as lowest price.
How can I fix this?

Comment: as i know the custom attribute will not affect any price in Magento, you need to use standard attributes, What is your logic, and why you don't use special price or price from-to?

Comment: I need custom price attribute so I use Price, Special Price, Clearance Price, Customer Group Price and display the lowest price in product details page.